# When append "true" in FileWriter, items delete from list

Tags: java, android, android-file

I’m trying to add an item to the list which is stored in a file. And I’m experiencing an odd behavior when I’m creating an instance of FileWriter to do so. If 'true' is passed to ‘appended’ parameter in the constructor (new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename, true))), the item doesn’t get added to the list. If I do not pass a parameter, the item is added to the list, but each time it overwrites an existing one. Can anyone help me with this?

What I've tried:

-using `FileOutputStream` - result the same, always overwriting items.

-added `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` - result the same, always overwriting items.

-`bw.append(convertTaskToGson(task));`

```
private List<Task> fillListFromGson(FileInputStream imputeStream) {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = prepareReadingFromFile(imputeStream);
    String receiveString;
    List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            String jsonNewObject = stringBuilder.toString();
            Task task = gson.fromJson(jsonNewObject, Task.class);
            taskList.add(task);
        }
        return taskList;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG_INTERNAL_FILE_ERROR, "cannot fill list from gson");
        return null;
    }
}


private boolean saveTaskToInternalStorage(Task task)  {
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(AppClass.getApplication().getFilesDir(), filename);

        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename, true));
        bw.write(convertTaskToGson(task));
        bw.newLine();
        bw.flush();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (bw != null)
            try {
            bw.close();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException ioe2) {
                return false;
            }
    } return true;
}
```

}

Expected result: new items to be added in the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite this block code:

```
BufferedReader  inputStream = new BufferedReader(new                      InputStreamReader(getFileInputStream(internalFileName)));
        while ((receiveString = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
            Task task = gson.fromJson(receiveString, Task.class);
            taskList.add(task);
        }
```

My mistake was incorrect inclusion StringBuilder,
and it broken the display of file items. After reinstall app - BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename, true))  works perfect to add new items in my file. Very stupid(